# Does a Swedish personal number expire?

Tags: sweden, national-id-number

I'm a Dutch citizen who has previously lived in Sweden for six years, but I have since moved on.  The Swedish version of what is called social security number, social insurance number, government service number, or otherwise, is the *personnummer*.  I got a *personnummer* assigned shortly after arriving and registering in the country.  Does this personnummer remain valid for the rest of my life, or is there some expiry?  I know that my Canadian social insurance number will expire.  What about my Swedish one?

Comment: you already got some answers that confirm that the number doesn't expire, however it could change. From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_identity_number_%28Sweden%29) : *If a person undergoes full gender reassignment surgery later in life, the serial number is changed to make the 'gender digit' (no. 9) conform with their new physical sex*

Comment: As a non-resident, your Canadian SIN will begin with the digit "9", indicating that it is temporary, and the card will have an explicit expiry date on it to match the expiry of your visa.

Comment: Can I use Swedish healthcare if my personnummer is "avregistrert" because I've lived abroad for longer than a year?

Comment: @user20508 Please ask a new question as a question, not as a comment, see [ask].

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I did a quick search on [Skatteverket's site](http://www.skatteverket.se/privat/folkbokforing/omfolkbokforing/personnumretsuppbyggnad.4.18e1b10334ebe8bc80001502.html), and found this:

> Personnumret får man av Skatteverket. Den som en gång fått ett personnummer behåller samma nummer livet ut. Det innebär att personnumret inte ändras vid t.ex. flyttning från eller till Sverige.

*My* (unprofessional, but I'm a native Swedish speaker) translation:

> Personal numbers are assigned by Skatteverket. After being assigned a number, you keep it for the rest of your life. This means that the number doesn't change for example by moving from or to Sweden.

So no, it doesn't expire.

Comment: you have removed the hyperlink

Comment: @Dirty-flow Thanks!

Comment: @unwind Please compare with https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/19364/19107

Comment: @VincentMiaEdieVerheyen Yeah, interesting but it's very unclear if being re-registered means that your personnumber no longer "exists" ...

Answer (score 7):

It seems that it remains valid for the rest of your life. I found this [forum discussion](http://www.thelocal.se/discuss/index.php?showtopic=25528), where several people confirm this:

> My wife had lived in the States for 15 years when we moved back to Sweden. We just went to Skatteverket in person with all our IDs and passports with us, and she had her personnummer "reactivated" as now living permanently in Sweden and not abroad.

Comment: Useful response; I'd still like to see a more authoritative source, though.

Comment: @drat Please compare with https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/19364/19107

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty certain it is yours for life. My mother left sweden to live in UK 40 years ago, and she occasionally returns and can still use it for opening bank accounts etc.

Answer (score 0):

Do the laws regarding 'Avregistrering från folkbokföringen' not imply that you might lose your personnummer? There are more conditions than just being dead (**19 §**). Cf. [**Folkbokföringslag (1991:481)**](https://www.riksdagen.se/sv/dokument-lagar/dokument/svensk-forfattningssamling/folkbokforingslag-1991481_sfs-1991-481#P18), which implies e.g. that if you move to a foreign country for a period of minimum one year, you are also de-registered from the 'folkbokföringen' **(20 §)**:

> **19 §**   Den som avlider eller dödförklaras skall avregistreras från folkbokföringen.
>
> **20 §**   Den som kan antas komma att regelmässigt tillbringa sin dygnsvila utom landet under minst ett år ska avregistreras från folkbokföringen som utflyttad om inte annat följer av fjärde stycket eller 14 §. Även den som kan antas komma att regelmässigt tillbringa sin dygnsvila både inom och utom landet ska avregistreras om han eller hon med hänsyn till samtliga omständigheter får anses ha sin egentliga hemvist utom landet.
>
> En person anses regelmässigt tillbringa sin dygnsvila utom landet om han eller hon under sin normala livsföring tillbringar dygnsvilan
> där minst en gång i veckan eller i samma omfattning men med en annan
> förläggning i tiden.
>
> Om en utlänning som måste ha uppehållstillstånd för att få vistas i landet saknar ett sådant tillstånd, ska det särskilt beaktas vid
> tillämpningen av första och andra styckena.

Comment: But does de-registration from *folkbokföringen* imply I no longer have a valid *personnummer*?

Comment: @gerrit Define having a valid personnummer.