# Activation of Swedish personummer

Tags: residence-cards, sweden

I was a resident of Sweden but moved after living there for 2 years. Can I move back with my minor son who holds a Swedish passport? Can I reactivate my Swedish personummer and get a duplicate card?

Comment: There is probably not much you can do from India. If you need help understanding the documents (ie validity) you can post scans (with your name etc blacked out).

Comment: Thanku for responding.  As I don't have the card,  the lifetime residence permit is stamped on the passport that I used then.  I only know the personummer so I am trying to find out if I can still get a duplicate ID card.

Comment: There was another question like this recently. The residence permit is cancelled if you leave Sweden for more than a year, apparently. You should be able to call skatteverket on the telephone and find out.

Comment: Some say that the ID validity is lifetime. So I guess it is not valid if the residence permit is not.  Thankyou for your help

Comment: No the cards are normally valid for five years I think.

Comment: The ID number is likely still valid. That is, if you moved to Sweden, you would use the same number. But, as @TomasBy said, your residence permit is unlikely to be valid.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I reactivate my Swedish personummer and get a duplicate card?

When you get your Swedish personal number, [it is valid for life](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/526/6).

Therefore, if you can get a visa or other form of permit to live in Sweden again, you can just resume using the personal number that you were assigned in the past.

However, whether you can simply move to Sweden with your son is another question — probably not, but do post the question separately.

Comment: While the number *itself* applies to you for life, that doesn't mean the rights that people tend to associate with the number (but actually come from registration) do. What matters is whether you are registered in Sweden (folkbokförd). And if a non-EEA citizen, have residence permit etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear exactly what you're asking about.

If you lived in Sweden before and were folkbokförd (registered in the population register) then you will have received a personnummer. You keep that number for life. However, you do not keep *the status of being folkbokförd* for life, which is the part that actually matters. If you leave Sweden, you cease to be folkbokförd as living in Sweden and lose the rights associated with that. If you return to Sweden and later get folkbokförd again they will reopen your record and reuse the number. I'm not sure what happens to Swedish ID cards (not the National kind citizens can get from police) if you leave, I suspect they may cancel it but I'm not sure, and in any case it's only 400 SEK to get a new one.

None of that has any relevance to whether you have the right to move back to Sweden or get a residence permit, though, if that's what you're asking. If you had a residence permit in Sweden and left, it is no longer valid. If you are an EEA or Swiss national, or moving together as a family member with one, you are allowed to move back to Sweden without needing a permit though.

If your son holds Swedish citizenship then, in theory, you can move back to Sweden with them as their family member under EEA rules, but that only works if you're moving *from an EEA country*, which I'm guessing (from your other posts) you're not. Your best bet is probably to apply to Migrationsverket for a new residence permit based on your son's citizenship?